# Improve performance SQL query in Python Cx_Oracle

Tags: python, sql, oracle, cx-oracle

I actually use Cx_Oracle library in Python to work with my database Oracle.

```
import cx_Oracle as Cx

# Parameters for server connexion
dsn_tns = Cx.makedsn(_ip, _port, service_name=_service_name)

# Connexion with Oracle Database
db = Cx.connect(_user, _password, dsn_tns)

# Obtain a cursor for make SQL query
cursor = db.cursor()
```

One of my query write in an INSERT of a Python dataframe into my Oracle target table among some conditions.

```
query = INSERT INTO ORA_TABLE(ID1, ID2) 
SELECT :1, :2
FROM DUAL 
WHERE (:1 != 'NF' AND :1 NOT IN (SELECT ID1 FROM ORA_TABLE)) 
   OR (:1 = 'NF' AND :2 NOT IN (SELECT ID2 FROM ORA_TABLE))
```

The goal of this query is to write only rows who respect conditions into the WHERE.

Actually ,this query works well when my Oracle target table have few rows. But, if my target Oracle table have more than 100 000 rows, it's very slow because I read through all the table in WHERE condition.

Is there a way to improve performance of this query with join or something else ?

End of code :

```
# SQL query incoming
cursor.prepare(query)

# Launch query with Python dataset
cursor.executemany(None, _py_table.values.tolist())

# Commit changes into Oracle database
db.commit()

# Close the cursor
cursor.close()

# Close the server connexion
db.close()
```

Comment: Are `id1` and `id2` defined as `not null` in `ora_table`?

Comment: Yes, there are not missing values in table. I use 'NF' instead.

Comment: But do the actual column definitions include `NOT NULL`? That's not the same thing as whether all values are populated.

Comment: I wasn't clear sorry. Yes, in Oracle target table definition, ID1 and ID2 are not NULLABLE

Comment: What is *Python dataset*? Did you mean pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution that could help: The sql that you have has an OR condition and only one part of this condition will be true for a given value. So I would divide it in two parts by checking the following **in the code** and constructing two inserts instead of one and at any point of time, only one would execute:
**IF :1 != 'NF'  then** use the following insert:

```
 INSERT INTO ORA_TABLE (ID1, ID2)
   SELECT :1, :2
     FROM DUAL
    WHERE (:1 NOT IN (SELECT ID1
                        FROM ORA_TABLE));
```

**and IF :1 = 'NF' then** use the following insert:

```
INSERT INTO ORA_TABLE (ID1, ID2)
   SELECT :1, :2
     FROM DUAL
    WHERE (:2 NOT IN (SELECT ID2
                        FROM ORA_TABLE));
```

So you check in code what is the value of :1 and depending on that use the two simplified insert. Please check if this is functionally the same as original query and verify if it improves the response time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Pandas, consider exporting your data as a table to be used as staging for final migration where you run your subquery only **once** and not for every row of data set. In Pandas, you would need to interface with [sqlalchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/oracle.html) to run the [`to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) export operation. Note: this assumes your connected user has such `DROP TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE` privileges.

Also, consider using `EXISTS` subquery to combine both `IN` subqueries. Below subquery attempts to run opposite of your logic for exclusion.

```
import sqlalchemy

...
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("oracle+cx_oracle://user:password@dsn")

# EXPORT DATA -ALWAYS REPLACING
pandas_df.to_sql('myTempTable', con=engine, if_exists='replace')

# RUN TRANSACTION
with engine.begin() as cn:
   sql = """INSERT INTO ORA_TABLE (ID1, ID2)
            SELECT t.ID1, t.ID2
            FROM myTempTable t
            WHERE EXISTS 
                (
                  SELECT 1 FROM ORA_TABLE sub
                  WHERE (t.ID1 != 'NF' AND t.ID1 = sub.ID1)
                     OR (t.ID1  = 'NF' AND t.ID2 = sub.ID2) 
                )
         """
   cn.execute(sql)
```